# How to add a custom wordpress isotope project portfolio pagination

Tags: pagination, wordpress-theming, jquery-isotope, wordpress

How can I add a pagination to my isotope portfolio page?
I want each filter work with a max item of 8 and use pagination to check next 8 items.
Below is my custom Template Name: Portfolio

```
<?php $t =& peTheme(); ?>
<?php $title = get_the_title(); ?>
<?php $pcontent = get_the_content(); ?> 
<?php $pcontent = apply_filters( 'the_content', $pcontent ); ?>
<?php $project =& $t->project; ?>
<?php list($portfolio) = $t->template->data(); ?>

<?php $content =& $t->content; ?>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <nav class="portfolio-filter clearfix">
                    <ul>
                        <?php $project->filter('',"keyword"); ?>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <hr class="main-hr-sm">
            <?php echo $pcontent; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row portfolio-container">
        <?php while ($content->looping()):
              $meta =& $content->meta();  ?>
            <div class="span3 portfolio-item <?php $project->filterClasses(); ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $t->image->resizedImgUrl($content->get_origImage(),1000,1000); ?>" class="fancybox" data-portfolio="<?php $content->slug(); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $t->image->resizedImgUrl($content->get_origImage(),460,300); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_html(get_the_content()); ?>">
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                    <?php $content->content(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination isn't built into Isotope so you'd have to build it from the ground up. [Here is a good tutorial](http://tannermoushey.com/2012/12/isotope-paging/) on how to do that with Wordpress and Isotope v1. Keep in mind the tutorial is using Isotope v1 so you'll have to change it if you want to use Isotope v2 but the general concepts in the tutorial should still be very helpful.